# Differentiate Between Parent & Child Categories

Tags: sidebar, categories, children

So I'm working with a non-wordpress theme called "Misty" and it uses this code to pull categories:

```
<li class="sidebox">
    <h3><?php _e('Categories','ml'); ?></h3>
    <ul id="catList">
        <?php
        if (function_exists('wp_list_categories'))
        {
            wp_list_categories("show_count=1&include=$catID&hierarchical=1&title_li=");
            wp_list_categories("show_count=1&child_of=$catID&hierarchical=1&title_li=");
        }
        else
        {
            wp_list_cats('optioncount=1');
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What sucks is that I cant style parent / child categories different, I want to indent child categories but they all go by class=category ID

`$catID` is how I want to filter posts. 3 different domains are coming to this blog and I am taking where they came from and filtering posts that way. So far I've filtered the category and showed that categories sub-categories, but the subcategories have no way to be styled.

What's a good work around to style the child categories? Is there somewhere I can just add another class to the child LI's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child ul comes with the class "children", so you can use this to target your css.
`ul.children li { }`

Even without that, though, you could just use the hierarchy of lists to target..

`ul#catList ul li { }` would target any li within a ul, within the #catList ID.

Comment: They are all showing up under #catList for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any problem making parent and child categories look different using CSS. Go to view source and you should see something like:

```
    <ul id="catList">

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/category/misc/" title="Miscellaneous and Unsorted Posts">Misc.</a> (1)
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/category/newsletter/" title="View all posts filed under Newsletters">Newsletters</a> (9)
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-79"><a href="http://yourdomain.com/category/newsletter/test/" title="just a test. delete whenever.">test</a> (1)
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

See where it says `ul class="children"` ? Make a default style for all category menu items and then override that with the "children" class (something like #catList ul.children li a {color: green} which would make all child category links green).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: :/ IDK why mines not doing that. I have them as subcategory posts in my wordpress admin panel, but when I view the page all of them are under catList